# How to serialize string into buffer and deserialize it at other end?

Tags: .net

We are using copydata method of win32 api to pass some data from c#.net to an vb6 application.

For that I need to serialize string into buffer.

I have converted my string value into a byte array using system.encoding... is this called serialization?

I need to serialize a string value into a buffer..  is my approach correct?

I am using the foll link to implement a receiver in vb6. I am confused how to implement the sender and receiver via c#.net. I need to send/receive a simple string..

Link: support.microsoft.com/kb/176058/en-us

Comment: It probably still has problems. Because why else would you be here? But we cannot help you with problems you don't post.

Comment: Can the sender be implemented via c#.net?

Comment: How do i Convert the string to a byte array using the CopyMemory() API in c#.net
Obtain the address of the byte array using the VarPtr() intrinsic function and copy the address and length of the byte array into a COPYDATASTRUCT structure.

Comment: Use the edit function of the question if you want to add further information. Don't post it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is called serialization.

You will need to find serialization code that works in VB6 as well as in C#, unless you have the option to call .NET from VB6 (technically possible... called reverse interop) to use an existing .NET serializer.

Comment: I need to pass string value to the app.. I have pasted the link that I am referring to above...